# Can't Display the total values in textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a program that counts the total values in the database and inserts the total values in a textbox named, txtCartItems.Text. The problem that I am encountering, is that whenever I add the Response.Write() code blocks, It displays the values that I inserted in the table, but it does not put the total values that I inserted in the txtCartItems.Text. And when I remove the Response.Write() code blocks, it displays the counted values in the txtCartItems.Text but I can't view the values that I recently added in the table. All I want is that, whenever I search for an item and add it, I can simultaneously view the values in the table and the total number of values that I inserted in the txtCartItems.Text.

```
Dim productQuantity As Integer
Dim totalPrice As Integer

Integer.TryParse(txtQuantity.Text, productQuantity)
totalPrice = productQuantity * Val(txtSellingPrice.Text)

'establish the first connection
con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;data source = " & Server.MapPath("Erika_Kyl_PointOfSales.mdb"))
con.Open()
query2 = "INSERT INTO tbl_Orders(product_name,product_category,product_quantity,total_price) VALUES('" & txtProductName.Text & "','" & txtCategory.Text & "','" & productQuantity & "','" & totalPrice & "')"
cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query2, con)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cmd.Dispose()
con.Close()

Response.Write(<script>alert('Orders Successfully Added!')</script>)
Response.Write("<script>window.location.reload()</script>")

'establish the second connection
con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;data source = " & Server.MapPath("Erika_Kyl_PointOfSales.mdb"))
con.Open()
query3 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalOrders FROM tbl_Orders"
cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query3, con)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
While dr.Read()
    txtCartItems.Text = dr("totalOrders").ToString()
End While
'align the value of textbox in center
txtCartItems.Style("text-align") = "center"
cmd.Dispose()
con.Close()

'clear the items in the textbox after adding them to tbl_Orders
txtISBN.Text = ""
txtProductName.Text = ""
txtCategory.Text = ""
txtQuantity.Text = ""
txtSellingPrice.Text = ""
```

Comment: Still i am not clear, however, as a suggestion, you can use `If dr.Read()`, as this will be having single values only ( `count(*)` ), instead of doing it with `while`

Comment: All I want is that whenever I search for an item and add it, it automatically adds to the table and i can see the total values in the table in the txtCartItems.Text.

Comment: Why do you need `Response.Write` and if it reloads , does that page_load sets the value in `txtCartItems` ?

Comment: Does this `Reload` in javascript , does all of thing, i mean it will reload the page and insert into DB and then set value in `txtCartItems` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see the oddity here, you are setting text for `txtCartItems` , after you are doing `Response.Write`, and that does reload your page before, even you set value if `txtCartItems` . So you can use following code to set the value and then do `reload`

```
Dim productQuantity As Integer
Dim totalPrice As Integer

Integer.TryParse(txtQuantity.Text, productQuantity)
totalPrice = productQuantity * Val(txtSellingPrice.Text)

'establish the first connection
con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;data source = " & Server.MapPath("Erika_Kyl_PointOfSales.mdb"))
con.Open()
query2 = "INSERT INTO tbl_Orders(product_name,product_category,product_quantity,total_price) VALUES('" & txtProductName.Text & "','" & txtCategory.Text & "','" & productQuantity & "','" & totalPrice & "')"
cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query2, con)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cmd.Dispose()
con.Close()

'establish the second connection
con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;data source = " & Server.MapPath("Erika_Kyl_PointOfSales.mdb"))
con.Open()
query3 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalOrders FROM tbl_Orders"
cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query3, con)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
While dr.Read()
    txtCartItems.Text = dr("totalOrders").ToString()
End While
'align the value of textbox in center
txtCartItems.Style("text-align") = "center"
cmd.Dispose()
con.Close()


'clear the items in the textbox after adding them to tbl_Orders
txtISBN.Text = ""
txtProductName.Text = ""
txtCategory.Text = ""
txtQuantity.Text = ""
txtSellingPrice.Text = ""

Response.Write(<script>alert('Orders Successfully Added!')</script>)
Response.Write("<script>window.location.reload()</script>")
```